# Find way, or other algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

What algorithm I need to use to achieve such a functionality? I had tried to look at longest way finding algorithms, but they are not suitable here. But I dont want give up, which way I need to look for?. Maybe anybody know, or faced such a problem before? Thanks for reply!

[image: sample]

Comment: By "find way" I would *guess* that you want to find the shortest path (or any path?) between two points in a maze (assumed from image), but you really should mention that explicitly - don't assume everyone is on the same page as you. Also, a Google search for "find way algorithm" returns exactly what you're looking for (if my assumptions are correct) in the first few results.

Comment: Nope, shortest path it's easy. I need to find longest path, circles on page its start and end points, and I need to connect them and not just connect, and achieve maximum straight lines maximum uniform filling.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is a [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), which can be implemented by recursion. On the maze solving problem, it would look something like the following.

1. Create a 2D array of bits (booleans) representing whether a particular space has been visited already, globally accessible.
2. Write a recursive function which takes `row` and `column` as parameters, as well as a list of previously visited nodes. This function should terminate under the following conditions.

   - The current row and column has already been visited.
   - The current row or column is out of bounds.
   - We have reached our goal. (It is not clear from the drawing whether you are trying to get out of the maze or get to some other point in the maze). In this case, terminate and output the current path (the list of previously visited nodes).

If the function does not terminate, then it should mark the current `row,column` pair as visited, and then make up to four recursive calls, depending on its location relative to the walls.

In particular, it should make the recursive call to any neighbor that does not require crossing over a wall.

The arguments to each recursive call are the new `row` and `column`, as well as a modified version of the list that it was passed. More specifically, it will append its own row and column to the end of the list, and pass this modified list **by value**.

Comment: I believe what you are proposing is a depth-first search. The non-recursive alternative is the breadth-first search. Breadth-first has an advantage in the case where the exit is located near the start. In the trivial case where the exit is adjacent to the start, breadth-first will find the solution immediately, whereas the depth-first search could spend hours traversing dead ends before getting back to checking that adjacent square.

Comment: @user3386109, Thank you for the note. Yes, this is DFS, although I think I never connected this myself because I always think of DFS and BFS as being on graphs, and my first conception of a grid is not of a graph, but you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and classic 'maze solver' is [**BFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

BFS is an algorithm that given a non weighted graph, finds the [shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) from the source to all nodes (or to the first target node).

BFS is guaranteed to be complete (always finds a path if such exists) and optimal (always finds the shortest path).

In your example the graph is the matrix of the maze (each cell is a node), and an edge `(u,v)` indicates you can move from cell `u` to cell `v`.

BFS is fairly easy to implement.

An alternative is using a more sophisticated [A* Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm). A* is usually faster than BFS with the right heuristic funciton. In your case, you can use the [manhattan distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) heuristics.